# Build Issue in AEM crx package manager

Tags: aem, crx

While building a package in AEM using crx package manager throwing an error "package build Undefined". But when I check under etc/packages/mypackages , package was created. Even there is no error or exception in error logs. How can I resolve this issue.

[Scrseenshot of error mesage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxgAP.png)
[Screenshot of package node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXUKb.png)

Comment: is "vlt:definition" node is getting created under "jcr:content" for your package  under /etc/packages/my_packages/yourpackage.zip

Comment: Yes it is getting created . I tried to create a fresh AEM instance Still I am getting same build issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:**

As per comment it was a **browser issue** (errors are visible in browser console) and updating to the latest version helped. In the case that is not helping it might be also worth to and disable some plugins as they can also affect CRX.

The suggestions below can be related to other types of errors:

It usually fails when some of the nodes cannot be added to the package. If I were in your shoes, I would verify if all the data you try to add is present in the package (I assume you are building your package from your content, not installing).

It might also be the case of the permissions to nodes however if you work on the clear instance then I assume you are using admin creds, you can also verify if you are not impersonated. You can also check if any of the nodes is not blocked however you should get feedback on this in logs.

It can be also the size of the data might be very big, or the nodes can be somehow corrupted, but again it should not the case for fresh instance.

Check also if you are using any specific configuration or filters for the package. It might be difficult to determine what is the issue without any information about the package or content itself.

Comment: Yes, I am building a package, not installing. When I cross verified the  package, content is present. I tried to build by adding filter to only 1 node i.e,cq:page still I am facing same build error.

Comment: I am trying with basic configuration. Also I checked with permissions since it is a fresh instance with admin creds I have all access to the nodes (filtered node and also to etc/packages/mypackages).

Comment: Could you verify three things? If there is an error during building the package with different content or without the content at all (without defining default root)? I see you are building from /content/dam and I remember some issues when the assets were having broken renditions, it would be good to specify if that is related to them or maybe package size.If you have any JS errors or warnings in browser console?Is it appearing in a particular browser or other browsers, too? The last I am thinking of is changing server logs level to debug and then checking if something specific appears in logs.

Comment: Thank you kamcie.It was a browser issue (chrome).I observed some console errors. I just updated to newer version , now its working.

Comment: No worries Pavan, I have added solution to my post, I'd be grateful for accepting it as I am working hard for reputation ;)